# SSRS - CASE statement with a List as the result

Tags: reporting-services, case

I'm new to this so please excuse me if this is a silly question.

Is it possible to use a CASE statement with a List as the result?

```
WHERE
 Service.Closed_Flag = 'False'
 AND Service.Board_name = CASE
   WHEN @SORT = 'True' 
    THEN (@BOARD)
   ELSE Service.Board_name
  END
```

@SORT is Boolean

@BOARD is a Drop-down List with option to allow multiple picks

The above code works fine unless I select more than one option for the @BOARD parameter resulting in a list.

I was hoping I could use IN within the CASE statement, THEN IN(@BOARD)?

SOLUTION:
I found a solution to my problem shortly after posting, always seems to happen to me. I can't answer my question until another 7 hours have passed to here is my solution:

CASE returns a scalar value only.

I adjusted my statement to the following which solved my problem:

```
WHERE
Service.Closed_Flag = 'False'
AND ((@SORT = 'True' AND Service.Board_name IN (@BOARD))
   OR
     (@SORT = 'False' AND Service.Board_name = Service.Board_name))
```

Comment: From some more searching I found the following:

CASE returns a scalar value only.

I adjusted my statement to the following which solved my problem:

    WHERE
    Service.Closed_Flag = 'False'
    AND ((@SORT = 'True' AND Service.Board_name IN (@BOARD))
       OR
         (@SORT = 'False' AND Service.Board_name = Service.Board_name))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem shortly after posting, always seems to happen to me.

CASE returns a scalar value only.

I adjusted my statement to the following which solved my problem:

```
WHERE
Service.Closed_Flag = 'False'
AND (
     (@SORT = 'True' AND Service.Board_name IN (@BOARD))
   OR
     (@SORT = 'False' AND Service.Board_name = Service.Board_name)
    )
```